# Facebook Friend Selector without FBML

Tags: facebook-fbml

Since facebook shut down FBML the friend selector tab I installed doesn't work anymore.
Is there an alternative that functions without FBML?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is connected to your page/application (i.e., if they Like it), you should be able to do something like this:

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  FB.init({
    appId  : '<?= $app_id; ?>',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });
  function friends() {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
  </script>

  <button onclick="friends();return false;">Show friends</button>
```

It would then be up to you to iterate over response.data and decide what to do. I just tested this on a page and it seems to work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Look for [Requests 2.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)